# Ubuntu wont recognize my internal hdd

Tags: hard-drive

I ran the windows installer with windows 7. I assumed Ubuntu would run my windows files, but my 1.5tb internal hard drive won't mount. Any help would be AWESOME!

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't run Windows files, it's binary incompatible with Windows. ...and the internal hdd can be accessed through /host.

Comment: Perhaps we can give you a better answer if you add some detail... what exactly have you tried to do, and what undesirable behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: Is your HDD state dynamic or basic? You can find that information from disk management in Windows. The problem may have occurred if your disk is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **Disks**
2. Choose the partition you want to mount
3. Click on the "play" icon. Maybe you are going to be requested to type the root password. You can also change the «Mount options»

[image]