# Can't install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Dell Vostro 3460

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, dell

I trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Dell Vostro 3460, Intel Core i7-3632QM, 1TB SATA + 32GB SSDR mSATA.

My goal is to install dual boot (Windows 8 is already installed).
After I boot from Ubuntu CD, I get the following screen:

[image]

(From this screen you can't define the disks and move forward with the installation.)

Comment: Did you try disabling Secure boot-UIEF from BIOS.

Sometimes it takes time to display the list of drives.

Comment: The Secure boot-UIEF is already off.

Comment: check that gparted shows the same or not.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Close the installer and restart again.

Comment: I have done this several times, even tried a different installation disk of Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/248427/ubuntu-wont-recognize-my-internal-hdd Can  you please check if the issue is because of disk being Dynamic partitioned.

Also try live boot and see if you can mount the hdd.

Comment: The disk is Basic.

Comment: Someone___________________________?

Comment: Ubuntu is Binary-Uncompatable with Windows. So that must be the case. This comment section is getting too chatty...

Answer (score 0):

Try to Boot from USB Stick. 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

or from your windows

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Hi. It also doesn't work.